# Is append the identity function for map?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

In doing some tests I've noticed that `append` always gives me the same output as input when using `map`:

```
#lang sicp
(map append '(1 2 3 4 5))
(map (lambda (x) x) '(1 2 3 4 5))
; (1 2 3 4 5)
; (1 2 3 4 5)
```

```
(map append '((1 2)(3 4)))
(map (lambda (x) x) '((1 2)(3 4)))
; ((1 2) (3 4))
; ((1 2) (3 4))
```

That seems pretty neat/unexpected to me. Is this in fact the case? If so, how does the `append` work to give the identity property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `append` procedure takes *zero or more* list arguments, and *a final argument* that can be any object. When the final argument is a list, the result of appending is a proper list. When the final argument is not a list, but other list arguments have been provided, the result is an improper list. When only one argument is provided, it is just returned. This behavior with one argument is exactly the behavior of an identity procedure.

```
> (append '(1 2) '(3))
(1 2 3)
> (append '(1 2) 3)
(1 2 . 3)
> (append '(1 2))
(1 2)
> (append 3)
3
```

The call `(map append '(1 2 3 4 5))` is equivalent to:

```
> (list (append 1)
        (append 2)
        (append 3)
        (append 4)
        (append 5))
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Here, `append` is just acting as an identity procedure, as described above.

Comment: thanks again. Your answers are so great and you are a genius with all the FP stuff. How did you get so good at it / any advice other than struggling through SICP?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words ;)  SICP is great; I worked through a book about functional programming by Bird and Wadler quite a few years ago that was very good and very helpful. I can't remember the title right now; that book used the Miranda programming language, which was in the early lineage of Haskell. The more recent versions of that book use Haskell. I would suggest spending a little bit of time with either or both of SML or Haskell to get a different perspective on functional programming. And then you just need to keep practicing....

Comment: I have a background in mathematics, and when I first started dabbling in functional programming it seemed like a very natural way to think about problems, e.g., recursion and transformations, thanks to my previous work in mathematics. If you haven't studied something like discrete mathematics and fundamentals of mathematical proofs, e.g., inductive proof techniques, those would be helpful things to look at, too.

Comment: Oh, and you should read at least one of the Scheme RnRS standards. These are great examples of language specs, and you will get a much better handle on what the language guarantees are vs. how implementations may behave. None of them, even R6RS, are very long.

Comment: @adabsurdum The book was "Introduction to Functional Programming". Not the most memorable title for a great book.

Comment: @adabsurdum cool, thanks for all that info, once I finish SICP I'll check out that second book!